# Google Analytics - UserID report get data

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've setup of google analytics USER-ID report where i send user id's, i want to get the details of each any userid using get or post request

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Google analytics only utilises  User Id for sessions unification through different devices. User I'd is not exposed in the reports. Consider using unique custom dimensions values to split sessions across users

Comment: what i did is adding a new view and enabling userID reporting, so the data i want is already there in user explorer, but i want to send get request to get it

Comment: User id is not available as a dimension in API requests